# push JSON object to array is not adding in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a problem I don't know what am doing wrong, below code need to push and JSON Object into array but its not updating, its only showing last pushed element.

```
var myData = {};
var id = 0;

$("a").on('click', function(){

  myData.answers = new Array();
  myAns = { id : id, answer : "my answer" };

  myData.answers.push(myAns);

  id++;

  console.log(myData);
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nf9aocvL/) for same, please help

Comment: This bit should be outside the event handler. You're recreating it everytime. `myData.answers = new Array();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `myData.answers = new Array();` out of the `click` event handler. You're reseting the array every time you click the link:

```
myData.answers = new Array();

$("a").on('click', function(){
    myAns = //etc
```

Comment: OMG, I am so stupid, i have been banging my head for 3 hours, thank you

Comment: Sometimes, you just need a extra set of eyes to spot the obvious :-)